flutter what consequences is there using macOS 14.7.6 and xcode 14.3.1
I’m currently developing a Flutter app and plan to get it working on iOS as well. I’m working on a Windows PC but have access to a MacBook Air for a while. However, I just found out that it's running macOS 12.7.6, so I can’t use the latest version of Xcode.
The app doesn’t need to be released, just tested on my iPhone 15 running iOS 17.5.1. Will I still be able to transfer my project and build it for testing? What potential issues or limitations should I be aware of?
Thanks!

it depend on your flutter version like flutter 3.13.x required Xcode 14+ and for 3.24.0 they just add recommend version to xcode 15 so it okay if you use xcode 14 for now but in the future if your project want to use newer flutter you have to update xcode I don't know why you can't update your macOs But you can try to  install Hackintosh on your pc to use xcode 15 as well

the mac is from 2017, so only supporting up to 12.7.6 sadly otherwise its fine. but thanks ill try looking into the hackintosh if thats something i can figure out :)
